# CartThrob Gateways

Tags: cartthrob, shopping-cart, checkout, subscriptions

I am trying to try see if I can use 2 different gateways on 2 different checkout pages in CT.

ie: on one checkout page I want to use Moneris for standard goods

but on another checkout page reserved for Subscriptions I want to only use Stripe

I was going to try and hardcode the gateways in each:

```
{exp:cartthrob:checkout_form return="subscription-checkout/order_info" secure_action="yes" gateway="stripe"}
```

and

```
{exp:cartthrob:checkout_form return="checkout/order_info" secure_action="yes" gateway="moneris_direct"}
```

But it seems there is no way to actually know if it is actually working.  HOw do I know if the correct gateway is being used?

Answer (score 1):

That's the correct way to specify a gateway for the transaction as long as they are not nested (which wouldn't work anyway). You can also pass the gateway short name via POST with a hidden input like this:

`<input type="hidden" name="gateway" value="stripe">`

Does your product/subscription order list the gateway that was used if you look at the order reports in the CP?

Comment: that report idea is a good one.  I will have to check.